# Plugging dynamic inputs into equations with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, dynamic

I am trying to get a form to display the result of equations that have dynamic fields plugged in but can't get thenewly created fields to display the answer. For example "footage2" should be plugged in to (math.ceil(footage/7) to give postQuantity2 but nothing is being shown. If anyone could explain where I went wrong and how it should be done I would be very grateful! Thank you so much. Here is a JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/gv0029/EH4yb/ and here is the

HTML:

```
<fieldset id="fence">
    <div id="inputFence1" class="clonedInputFence">
        <fieldset id="fenceDescripton">
            <legend><strong>Fence Description</strong>

            </legend>
            <label>Footage:
                <input type="number" id="footage" name="footage" value="" />
            </label>
            <select name="fenceHeight" id="fenceHeight">
                <option value="select">Select Fence Height</option>
                <option value="6" id="fH6">6 Ft.</option>
                <option value="8" id="fH8">8 Ft.</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset id="post">
            <legend><strong>Post Type</strong>

            </legend>

            <label>Post Quantity:
                <input type="postQuantity" name="postQuantity" id="postQuantity" value="" />
            </label>
            <select name="postMeasurements" id="postMeasurements">
                <option value="select">Select Post Measurements</option>
                <option value="23/8 x .065 x 8" id="23/8 x .065 x 8">2 3/8 x .065 x 8</option>
                <option value="23/8 x .095 x 8" id="23/8 x .095 x 8">23/8 x .095 x 8</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>

    </div>
</fieldset>
<div>
    <input type="button" id="btnAddFence" value="Add Another Fence" />
    <input type="button" id="btnDelFence" value="Remove Fence" />
</div>
```

and JS:

```
//Quantity for Posts
$('#footage, #manualOverrideNo').bind('keypress keydown keyup change', function(){

    var footage = parseFloat($(':input[name="footage"]').val(),10);
    var total = '';

    if(!isNaN(footage)){
        total = Math.ceil(footage /7);
        $(':input[name="postQuantity"]').val(total.toString());
    } else {
        $(':input[name="postQuantity"]').val("");
    }
});

//Quantity for additional posts
$('#footage, #manualOverrideNo').bind('keypress keydown keyup change', function(){

    var footage = parseFloat($(':input[name="footage"]').val(),10);
    var total = '';
    $field = $(event.target).closest(':input[name="footage"]'); // event.target is the element that first registered the event
    index = $($field).data('index');
    if(!isNaN(footage)){
        total = Math.ceil(footage /7);
        $(':input[name="postQuantity"][data-index="' + index + '"]').val(total.toString());
    } else {
        $(':input[name="postQuantity"]').val("");
    }
});



//Dynamic Fence Input Fields
$('#btnAddFence').click(function() {
    var num     = $('.clonedInputFence').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
    var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);      // the numeric ID of the new input field being added

    // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value
    var newElem = $('#inputFence' + num).clone().attr('id', 'inputFence' + newNum);

    //Fieldset creation
    newElem.find('fieldset').attr('id', 'fence' + newNum);

    //Fence Description 
    newElem.find("select[name=fenceHeight]").attr('id', 'fenceHeight' + newNum).attr('name', 'fenceHeight' + newNum);
    newElem.find(':input[name="footage"]').attr('id', 'footage' + newNum).attr('name', 'footage' + newNum);

    //Post Type
    newElem.find(':input[name="postQuantity"]').attr('id', 'postQuantity' + newNum).attr('name', 'postQuantity' + newNum);
    newElem.find("select[name=postMeasurements]").attr('id', 'postMeasurements' + newNum).attr('name', 'postMeasurements' + newNum);


    //Grouping by index
    newElem.data('index', num);

    // insert the new element after the last "duplicable" input field
    $('#inputFence' + num).after(newElem);

    // enable the "remove" button
    //$('#btnDel').attr('disabled','');
    $('#btnDelFence').removeAttr('disabled');
});

$('#btnDelFence').click(function() {
    var num = $('.clonedInputFence').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
    $('#inputFence' + num).remove();     // remove the last element

    // enable the "add" button
    //$('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','');
    $('#btnAddFence').removeAttr('disabled');

    // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
    if (num-1 == 1)
        $('#btnDelFence').attr('disabled','disabled');
    });

    $('#btnDelFence').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware bind will only work for elements that are present at the time you call it so you can either wrap your bind method in a function and call it when elements are created
or use `jquery.on` to bind to elements created dynamically like:

```
 $(document).on('keypress keydown keyup change','#footage, #manualOverrideNo',
        function(){ .....
```

The issue I outlined still stands but looking at your fiddle you have another issue.

the second `'#footage'` is has an id of `#footage2` and you are not binding to that.

set the id to simply `2` and the classname to `manualOverrideNo`

the try

```
  $(document).on('keyup','.manualOverrideNo',function(){
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
      var manualOverrideNo = $('#'+id).val();
  });
```

now you have the right value and can do something with it

Comment: @gv0029 Andrew is correct that you are no longer bound to the element as soon as you update the ID (which you must do, as you cannot have duplicate IDs). His solution of binding by the class name, using jQuery's `.on()`, is correct. Note that you can also bind to the element ID using "starts with", e.g. `$(document).on('keyup', '[id^=footage]', function() {//stuff});` Well done Andrew. *Please remember to upvote/accept andrew's answer when ready to close the question.*